# Appropriate table schema for multiple many-to-many relationship and concerns about uniqueness

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema, identity, junction-table

I am trying to create a simple database to store various job listings. For the purpose of this question let's say I have 5 distinct job offers:

```
╔══════════════════╦═════════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║      title       ║      level      ║         skills          ║
╠══════════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ Python Developer ║ Trainee, Junior ║ Python, SQL, Django     ║
║ Python Developer ║ Trainee, Junior ║ Python, REST API, Flask ║
║ Python Developer ║ Senior          ║ Python, REST API, Flask ║
║ QA Engineer      ║ Mid             ║ React, AWS              ║
║ QA Engineer      ║ Senior, Expert  ║ Java, AWS, SQL          ║
╚══════════════════╩═════════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

As you can see each job offer consist of three things: title (just job title), level (experience level required by the employer) and skills (needed for particular job position). Now, because I want to put everything into relational database model I cannot just leave it as it is, I need to reorganize this so that everything works well (in other words I need to satisfy normal forms criteria). So I have decided I need to create 3 new tables based on columns: `title`, `level` and `skills` + 2 bridge(linking) tables: `title_level` and `title_skills` because there are many-to-many relationships. After creating these 5 tables and inserting appropriate data into each one of them everything looks like this:[image]

And the result after making joins looks like this:

[image]

It's not bad, but I have my doubts.  **My main question is: Is this appropriate table schema for the situations like this one?** My main concerns are the uniqueness of each job posting. If you look at `title` table you'll notice that I decided to treat every job title as a separate value so that each one of them have unique id (it's quite logicall: 5 job titles and 5 id's). But I'm curious if this right to do things in such a way because this approach led me to situation where title column  in `title` table have duplicates. So maybe should I get rid of duplicates and leave this table with only two rows: `Python Developer` and `QA Engineer`? But if I do it this way how then can I distinguish the job offers from each other? I mean there will be no uniqueness unless I put id columns in some table (I don't know where).

Comment: in your model you are missng the "Job Position" table. This one should be related to "Position_Level" and "Position_Skill". Title can be just a property of the job position; or you could model it separately (I don't see the need here).

Comment: Wouldn't skills be related to the level, rather than the title?

Comment: @The Impaler I need further explanation of your idea. What would be a purpose of this "Job Position" table and and what new columns would it need?

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc
Do you mean to create a linking table between the "skill" table and the "level" table? And what columns would go in it?

Comment: @beginsql Your ER model is missing the entity "job offers", that I would consider a main entity. This entity should have a N:1 relationship with "title", M:N against "level" and also M:N against "skill".

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd create this job posting database.  I'm keeping your `Title`, `Level`, and `Skills` tables.  I'm creating these two junction tables.

```
Job Posting
-----------
Job Posting ID
Title ID
Level ID
Posted Timestamp
Need By Timestamp
Expires Iimestamp
...
```

where Job Posting ID is the primary key and an index on (Title ID, Level ID)

```
PostingSkills
-----------
Job Posting ID
Skills ID
Experience needed in months
...
```

where (Job Posting iD, Skills ID) is the primary key.

Comment: If I did it in your way then the title column in "Title" table wouldn't have to have duplicates, am I correct? My point is that the whole idea with duplicate job titles in "Title" table and their unique IDs was to preserve separateness of each job offer. But if I understand correctly you want to move this separateness (uniqueness) of each job offer into "Job posting" table, and more specifically into Job Posting ID column so that each job posting has its own Job posting ID yes?

Comment: @beginsql: Yes, my goal was to create unique job postings.  20 job posting rows means 20 different job postings.  I left the Title table alone because most job titles are generic, but a particular poster might have unique job titles.

Comment: Sorry for my inquisitiveness but if one row in your Job Posting table means 1 particular job posting then what if specific job posting have 2 levels like it is for example in my first row in my main question("Python Developer" title)? I need two rows to illustrate this relationship and if I do this in this way then their Job Posting IDs are different which means that they dont belong to the same job posting (which is of course not true). Anyway, thanks you for your patience in answering my questions.

Comment: @beginsql; So, what you're saying, is a job can have more than one position.  That is a different definition of "job" than most of us use.  It's your database, make it look however you wish.